# Default value if input field empty

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a search form with various field but i want to set a default into the url if the field is empty:

```
<input type="text" name="price-max" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price" >
```

and when the form is submited my url looks something like this

```
search.php?location=location&category=Category&status=lease&price-max=
```

instead i want a default value so that when i submit the form with an empty price field the url should like.

```
search.php?location=location&category=Category&status=lease&price-max=999
```

Comment: define a value in the input field itself

Comment: Do that server-side, something like `$var = empty($_GET['price-max']) ? 999 : $_GET['price-max'];`

Comment: Is there JavaScript allowed?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the docs have an example like my previous comment: [Example #3 Assigning a default value](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: yes js is allowed as long as it works , because i'm using it to query a phpmyadmin database, i should be able to insert changed GEt value into my query

Comment: So, basically, it doesn't really matter the url? You just want the default value if the input is empty? If so, my previous comments (that you seemed to overlook) are what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Just) Do it* **server-side**:

```
$price_max = empty($_GET['price-max']) ? 999 : $_GET['price-max'];
//                                       /\ default value
```

That way, when you use `$price_max` in your query, it will be either user input or the default value (`999` - or whatever value you decide to go with).

You don't even have to mess with the url to achieve that.

---

The previous code is the same as:

```
if(empty($_GET['price-max'])){
    $price_max = 999; // default value
}else{
    $price_max = $_GET['price-max'];
}
```

---

**Sidenotes:**

- You could combine the above code with [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php);
- There's info / example in the docs: [Example #3 Assigning a default value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary);
- You didn't show the php code, but make sure you are [protected against sql-injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php);
- You could put your default value as [`placeholder`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) in the input, just so the user 'sees' something in there.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define feild default value

```
<input type="text" name="price-max" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price" value="999">
```

Comment: what happen if user backspaces the text field.

Comment: it still empty value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put default value, you should define value in each input field.

```
<input type="text" value="defualt_value" name="price-max" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the `form` directly, call a function to validate the form fields. In that function, check if that field is empty and then add your default value. Finally that function submits the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

**1st method**

Define `value attribute` in your `input field` but this will show your `default value` in `text field`

```
<form method = "GET" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="price-max" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price" value = "<?php echo  $_GET['price-max'] ? $_GET['price-max'] : 999 ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submt">
```

if you didn't input then it will carry `price-max = 999` otherwise whatever you will type

**2nd Method**

Use `jQuery` or `javascript` for this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method = "GET" action="search.php" id="my_form">
<input type="text" name="price-max" id="price-max" class="form-control" placeholder="Max Price">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_form").submit(function() {           
            if($("#price-max").val()=="") {             
                    $("#price-max").val('999');         
                            }
        });
     });
</script>
```

I have added `id` `attribute` to `form` and `price-max` field

Answer (score 0):

**in controller example**

```
public function getMessages(Request $request){
    $page = request('page', 1);
    $limit = request('limit', 100);
    $status = request('status', 'all');
    $sort = request('sort', 'asc');
    $id = request('id', 'asc');
    $referenceId = request('referenceId', '');
    $from = request('from', '');
    $to = request('to', '');
    $ack = request('ack', '');
    .......
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  In controller where these methods actually exist? Is this laravel? Please [edit] your question with the intent to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.